# firefox cannot access http://my_machine_name in Firefox

Tags: networking, servlets, weblogic, localhost

I am using Weblogic seever for local testing..

I cannot cannot access http://my_machine_name in Firefox (e.g. http://xyz123)

The same can be accessed in IE/Safari

Please help me. Thank you

Comment: It says "Firefox can't find the server at xyz123."

Comment: Try http://127.0.0.1 , if it works, it's some sort of DNS issue.

Comment: Eve 127.0.0.1 does not work ...Also http://my_machine says "The dnsserver returned: Server Failure: The name server was unable to process this query. :"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no fundamental reason why one browser would work and the other fail, so it's likely down to configuration of the browsers.

Following up JoseK's question - can you access your local WebLogic Server instance using an IP address rather than the machine name?

Also, is it possible that you've got a corporate HTTP proxy server configured for Firefox, but that it's not being used in IE? (I've hit this before on client site myself)

Last of all, can you definitely check via WebLogic Server's server log files or netstat that it's definitely binding to your public IP address on port 80 (and not using something else like a loopback address, for example?)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it has something to do with your problem but i know that firefox has its own dns-cache. Maybe (and only maybe) would it help to turn it off.